# Cierre de formularios al copiar informacion

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-forms

Buen día.

Estoy trabajando en un sistema creado en winformrs con Vb.net y c#, el sistema ya crecio en gran medida y funciona bien, solo que se cierra cuando se copian información mostrada en alguno de los grid de los formularios, se copia mediante las teclas ctrl+c, despues de presionar las teclas el sistema se bloquea y se cierra.

como aclaración esto sucede en el sistema de producción por decirlo así, al ejecutar el .exe despues de loguerase y consultar info todo normal pero al copiar se cierra, he intentado replicar con el codigo local desde el debug pero desde ahi se copia normalmente, no se cierra ni manda alguna excepcion.

si tienen alguna idea, de ante mano se los agradezco.

Saludos.

Comment: Que acciones haces para copiar los datos del grid? muestra el código

Comment: Como el error acontece en otro computador, vas a tener que capturar el error en un `try/catch` y guardar en un log. Con la información que has dado es imposible responderte